# Loop to build virtual disparity image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, depth, stereoscopy, disparity-mapping

I'm trying to implement the homogeneous transformation from the disparity image to the virtual disparity image, following the paper of Suganuma et. al. "***An Obstacle Extraction Method Using Virtual Disparity Image***".
After doing the matrix computations described in the paper, I reach a global homogeneous transformation matrix that describes just a translation of -27.7 in the direction v, which makes sense.

Now, to make this transformation, I implemented a loop in MATLAB:

```
virtual_disparity=zeros(size(disparityMap));

%Homogeneous vector of a point of the disparityMap U=[u/d v/d 1/d 1]' (4x1)
U = zeros(4,1);
U_v = zeros(4,1);
for i=1:size(disparityMap,1)    %Rows-->y
    for j=1:size(disparityMap,2)    %Cols-->x
        d = disparityMap(i, j); % (i,j)-->(cols,rows)-->(y,x)
        U = [j/d i/d 1/d 1]'; % [u/d v/d 1/d 1]'
        U_v = B*U; % B is the whole homogeneous transform
        U_v = U_v./U_v(4);
        u_v_x = U_v(1);   %u_v_j
        u_v_y = U_v(2);   %u_v_i
        if((u_v_x>1) && (u_v_x<=size(virtual_disparity, 2)) && (u_v_y>1) && (u_v_y<=size(virtual_disparity, 1)))
            virtual_disparity(round(u_v_y), round(u_v_x)) = disparityMap(i, j);
        end
    end
end
```

Now, the problem is that the virtual disparity that I get doesn't make any sense, since it doesn't even corresponds with the transformation described in B, which, as I said is:

```
1.0000    0    0.0000         0
0    1.0000    0.0000  -27.7003
0         0    1.0000         0
0         0         0    1.0000
```

These are the disparity and the virtual disparity respectively:

**Disparity Map:**
[image: disparity map]

**Virtual Disparity:**
[image: virtual disparity]

I've been rechecking all day long and I don't find the error.

Comment: I never heard about "virtual disparity", so I admint this is a try, but I am  thinking about homogenous coordinates. I think your transformation B has to be applied to a 3D-like homogeneous coordinate which should be like '[X,Y, Z, 1]' and not the "already normalized form" [X/Z, Y/Z, 1, 1/Z] (as you see if you normalize "before doing anything else" the last value cannot be 1). If I am talking about completely different, please be kind and explain this to me: I am courious!

Comment: @marcoresk I'm not normalizing it, since I do not divide the last element, which remains 1:  `U = [j/d i/d 1/d 1]';`It is just that the method uses this coordinates, which incorporates info from the image pixel and the disparity (inversely proportional to the distance. I allready found what is wrong, which is related, but in the final coordinates. Thanks anyway. I have to go, I will post the answer today ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a colleage helped me and we found whats wrong. I was suposing that the final coordinates U_v would be given in the form `[u v 0 1]'`, which actually doesn't make much sense. Actually they were given, as the input coordinates in the form `[u/d v/d 1/d 1]'`. So, instead of normalizing them dividing by the element 4, as I was doing, I must divide them by the element 3 (`1/d`). 
To sum up, it was just an error in the line:

```
U_v = U_v./U_v(4);
```

Which must be substituted by:

```
U_v = U_v./U_v(3);
```

Now the image, although is a little bit more sparse than I thought, it's similar to the one of the paper:
[image: Correct virtual disparity image]